# Iterating and Writing Pandas Dataframe NaNs back to MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, iteration, pandas

I'm attempting to write the results of a regression back to MySQL, but am having problems  iterating through the fitted values and getting the NaNs to write as null values.  Originally, I did the iteration this way:

```
for i in dataframe:
    cur = cnx.cursor()
    query = ("UPDATE Regression_Data.Input SET FITTEDVALUES="+(dataframe['yhat'].__str__())+" where timecount="+(datafrane['timecount'].__str__())+";")
    cur.execute(query)
    cnx.commit()
    cur.close()
```

.....which SQL thew back to me by saying:

```
 "mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NaN'
```

So, I've been trying to filter out the NaNs by only asking Python to commit when yhat does not equal NaN:

```
for i in dataframe:
    if cleandf['yhat']>(-1000):
        cur = cnx.cursor()
        query = ("UPDATE Regression_Data.Input SET FITTEDVALUES="+(dataframe['yhat'].__str__())+" where timecount="+(datafrane['timecount'].__str__())+";")
        cur.execute(query)
        cnx.commit()
       cur.close()
```

But then I get this:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

So, I try to get around it with this in my above syntax:

```
if cleandf['yhat'][i]>(-1000):
```

but then get this:

```
ValueError: Can only tuple-index with a MultiIndex
```

And then tried adding itterows() to both as in:

```
 for i in dataframe.iterrows():
        if cleandf['yhat'][i]>(-1000):
```

but get the same problems as above.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, but assume it's something with iterating in Pandas DataFrames.    But, even if I got the iteration right, I would want to write Nulls into SQL where the NaN appeared.

So, how do you think I should do this?

Comment: Have you tried using `write_frame` and `read_frame`, like in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14431646/how-to-write-pandas-dataframe-to-sqlite-with-index/14432914#14432914)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have a complete answer, but perhaps I have some tips that might help.  I believe you are thinking of your `dataframe` as an object similar to a SQL record set.

```
for i in dataframe
```

This will iterate over the column name strings in the dataframe.  `i` will take on column names, not rows.

```
dataframe['yhat']
```

This returns an entire column (`pandas.Series`, which is a `numpy.ndarray`), not a single value.  Therefore:

```
dataframe['yhat'].__str__()
```

will give a string representation of an entire column that is useful for humans to read.  It is certainly not a single value that can be converted to string for your query.

```
if cleandf['yhat']>(-1000)
```

This gives an error, because again, `cleandf['yhat']` is an entire array of values, not just a single value.  Think of it as an entire column, not the value from a single row.

```
if cleandf['yhat'][i]>(-1000):
```

This is getting closer, but you really want `i` to be an integer here, not another column name.

```
for i in dataframe.iterrows():
    if cleandf['yhat'][i]>(-1000):
```

Using `iterrows` seems like the right thing for you.  However, `i` takes on the value of each row, not an integer that can index into a column (`cleandf['yhat']` is a full column).

Also, note that pandas has better ways to check for missing values than relying on a huge negative number.  Try something like this:

```
non_missing_index = pandas.isnull(dataframe['yhat'])
cleandf = dataframe[non_missing_index]
for row in cleandf.iterrows():
    row_index, row_values = row
    query = ("UPDATE Regression_Data.Input SET FITTEDVALUES="+(row_values['yhat'].__str__())+" where timecount="+(row_values['timecount'].__str__())+";")
    execute_my_query(query)
```

You can implement `execute_my_query` better than I can, I expect.  However, this solution is not quite what you want.  You really want to iterate over all rows and do two types of inserts.  Try this:

```
for row in dataframe.iterrows():
    row_index, row_values = row
    if pandas.isnull(row_values['yhat']):
        pass # populate the 'null' insert query here
    else:
        query = ("UPDATE Regression_Data.Input SET FITTEDVALUES="+(row_values['yhat'].__str__())+" where timecount="+(row_values['timecount'].__str__())+";")
    execute_my_query(query)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Awesome. Very helpful.  I'll let you know if I have any more questions.