# SQL query results into table in Python

Tags: python

I want to put my SQL code results into a table/data frame in Python. I have typed the code below and wanted to know what additional code I need to use in order to do this:

```
import pandas as pd    
f = pd.read_csv("/Users/sandeep/Downloads/Python/baseball.csv", header=0)

q = """
      select player, year,
              case when team='CHN' then 1 else 0 end as team_flag
      from  f
      where year=2006;      
    """
```

Comment: Documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#sql-queries

Comment: Also is `from  f` your intention to get values from a CSV file? Why are you using SQL to query a CSV?

Comment: Yakym's solution is best, but if you are stuck with a CSV file, you can convert it to an in-memory sqlite3 database, and use pandas.read_sql on _that_ driver. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/14432914/1930462

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use pandas.read_sql()

```
df = psql.read_sql(q,db)
```

To create the db connection, I suggest you use the following:

```
import psycopg2

db= psycopg2.connect("dbname='template1' user='dbuser' host='localhost' password='dbpass'")
```

Comment: Thanks for the above guys. I'm using the csv so that I can have some data to practice with. I could in the instance above code the query as it is simple and not use sql and get back the same results. But for more complex queries where I have to merge multiple tables and do subqueries.. sql would make it easier. for me. How do I get my results from the sql query into the same folder as my f table. I tried  the import psycopg2 but it failed even when I tried pip install psycopg2 in the terminal. Being new to python if someone could give me the code it would be a great help to get me using sql.

Comment: Also I didn't understand the concept of a connection. In R for example I could import the sql package and then just code in sql and any data created from my sql query would be in the same place as any other data set.

Comment: post here how you tried to establish the db connection

Comment: Hi mate. I've managed to get it working now. Thanks for getting back to me.

Answer (score 1):

Your pandas code suggests that you are reading from a `.csv` file, not an SQL database. In such case, you do not need to do anything else and `f` will in fact contain the DataFrame.

The syntax for obtaining a DataFrame from an SQL table can be found [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html):

At minimum, you will need two arguments: a query and a connection (which may be a string). Your query may be something like `SELECT player, year, case FROM table_name WHERE team='CHN' AND year=2006`. The connection string can be `sqlite:////full_path.sqlite` or `sql_flavor://user:password@host:path`.

It is arguably easier to add your indicator within the DataFrame rather than suing `SQL`; say `df['team'] = df['team'] == 'CHN'` should do it.